# How do I silently open a new tab in netrw on vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 4 
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 15

nmap <C-n> :Lexplore <bar> vertical resize 30 <CR>
```

Right now, `<CR>` opens the files in a new tab which is what I like but the problem is I automatically go to that tab. Is there any way to silently make a new tab?

I like to open everything up in bulk before coding.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I just used vscode now lol